# JAVA two mouse listeners not working together

Tags: java, mouselistener, esri

I have the following two mouse listeners. The issue is that when I don't click the mouse button and move around, "MouseMove....." will print. When I click the mouse, "MouseDown...." will print. However, If i click and hold the mouse button down and then move the mouse while the mouse button is held down, only the first three movements register for onMouseMove and then it stops printing. Any idea how to resolve this?

sameple output (note: many other mouse movements were made after the last print statement for MouseMove):

```
MouseMove: 1819.0           321.0
MouseMove: 1819.0           319.0
MouseMove: 1819.0           316.0
MouseMove: 1819.0           315.0
MouseDown: 1819.0           315.0
MouseMove: 1818.0           315.0
MouseMove: 1817.0           315.0
MouseMove: 1816.0           317.0
```

and the two listeners (this class extends com.esri.arcgis.controls.ITOCControlEventsAdapter) :

```
@Override
public void onMouseMove(ITOCControlEventsOnMouseMoveEvent theEvent) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    final String METHOD_NAME = "onMouseMove(ITOCControlEventsOnMouseMoveEvent)";
    Point mousePoint = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    System.out.println("MouseMove: " + mousePoint.getX() + "           " + mousePoint.getY());

}

@Override
public void onMouseDown(ITOCControlEventsOnMouseDownEvent theEvent) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    final String METHOD_NAME = "onMouseDown(ITOCControlEventsOnMouseDownEvent)";
    Point mousePoint = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    System.out.println("MouseDown: " + mousePoint.getX() + "           " + mousePoint.getY());
}
```

Comment: I think the action is not `onMouseMove` . It is called `onMouseDragg`

Comment: Are you looking to implement the [mouseDragged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html#mouseDragged-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-) event?

Comment: well onMouseDrag is not available in the class which I extend. I also tried implementing the interface MouseMotionListener which has a mouseDragged event I can override, however nothing ever printed when I throw the same logic in the method

Comment: These are not standard Java. You will need to read about com.esri.arcgis.controls.   If you were creating a basic AWT or Swing application, this would be easier to answer.